# remove pipe from value column and new 6 column in same table with single separated value in sql

Tags: sql

The table detail shown below:

```
REPORT_ID                  ATTR          VALUE
INV_2017-08-29T06:00:00  /s-1/          /s-1/|7500|25|LPG|3610.94870820629|3526.84971279216|3523.3882574674
```

Comment: tag the DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle,etc..) which u r using.

Comment: can you give us required sample output?

Comment: May we ask why you didn't parse your pipe separated data into separate columns when you read in the source file to your database (assuming that is how the data got there in the first place) ?

Comment: What is the result you want?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

One method is `XML` node method if you are working with `SQL Server`

```
select distinct REPORT_ID, ATTR,
     a.value ('/A[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [Value1],
     a.value ('/A[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [Value2],
     a.value ('/A[3]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [Value3],
     a.value ('/A[4]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [Value4],
     a.value ('/A[5]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [Value5],
     a.value ('/A[6]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [Value6],
     a.value ('/A[7]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [Value7]

      from 
(
    SELECT REPORT_ID, ATTR, CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(Value,'|', '</A><A>')+'</A>' AS XML) AS Value 
    FROM [AmmDb].[dbo].[IP_REPORT]
) A CROSS APPLY Value.nodes ('/A') as split(a)
```

Result :

```
REPORT_ID                ATTR   Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  .....       Value7
INV_2017-08-29T06:00:00 /s-1/   /s-1/   7500    25      LPG  3610.94870820629       3523.3882574674
```

Comment: can i run this as it is or some changes .i got one error must declare scalar variables @data

Comment: my table name is   FROM < [AmmDb].[dbo].[IP_REPORT]> this